Access Violation Exception when using Quick Edit in the Delphi IDE on form
When using the Quick Edit feature in the IDE, the following exception is raised every time I try to save the changes:

Access violation at address 00000000 in module 'bds.exe'. Read of address 00000000.

It happens every time I click on the green checkmark as can be seen on the image below:

It doesn't matter what I type into the Name or Caption.
I'm using Delphi 11.3 Community Edition. I've tried to restart the IDE, but the problem persists. I've also tried to repair the installation, but it didn't help. I've also tried to run the IDE as an administrator, but it didn't help either.
How can I fix this issue?

File a bug report at Embarcadero.

Embarcadero's new bug tracker is live at https://qp.embarcadero.com

Is this a TMS WEB Core Project?
I tested this on my side on Delphi 12 with VCL and FMX, but I don't get the same error as you. However when I test it on a TMS WEB Core project, then I get the same error as well.
So I think this isn't an issue on Embarcadero's side with the IDE. It might be something with TMS Web Core assuming that is what you're using here?

yes. tms web core
